# Conditionally remove rows from a database using R

Tags: r

```
ID       Number      Var
1        2           6
1        2           7
1        1           8
1        2           9
1        2           10
2        2           3
2        2           4
2        1           5
2        2           6
```

Each person has several records.
There is only one record of a person whose *Number* is 1, the rest is 2.
The variable *Var* has different values for the same person.

When the *Number* equals to 1, the corresponding *Var* (we call it P) is different for different persons.

Now, I want to delete the rows whose *Var* > P for every person.

At the end, I want this

```
    ID       Number      Var
    1        2           6
    1        2           7
    1        1           8
    2        2           3
    2        2           4
    2        1           5
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want to delete all rows whose `var` > P, or only those corresponding to `Number` == 1 whose `var` > P?

Comment: the question is not clear, please explain it again. Also, please provide a reproducible example. here is how you do it for this particular problem `my_df <-
data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
Number = c(2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2), 
Var  = c(6,7,8,9,10,4,5,6,7))`

Comment: Sorry. I have reedited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::first` where `Num==1` to get the first `Var` value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Flag=first(Var[Number==1])) %>% 
       filter(Var <= Flag) %>% select(-Flag)

#short version and you sure there is a one Num==1
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Var <= Var[Number==1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread(
"ID       Number      Var
1        2           6
1        2           7
1        1           8
1        2           9
1        2           10
2        2           3
2        2           4
2        1           5
2        2           6")

dt[, .SD[Var <= Var[Number==1]], ID]
#    ID Number Var
# 1:  1      2   6
# 2:  1      2   7
# 3:  1      1   8
# 4:  2      2   3
# 5:  2      2   4
# 6:  2      1   5
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be

```
df1[with(df1, Var <= ave(Var * (Number == 1), ID, FUN = function(x) x[x!=0])),]
#  ID Number Var
#1  1      2   6
#2  1      2   7
#3  1      1   8
#6  2      2   3
#7  2      2   4
#8  2      1   5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Number = c(2L, 
 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Var = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```